# React/Jest Select element onChange values not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have the following code to test the value of the Select element after changing:

```
it("changes value after selecting another field", () => {
  doSetupWork();
  let field = screen.getByLabelText("MySelectField");
  expect(field).toHaveValue("");

  fireEvent.change(field, { target: { value: "1" } });

  // Insert one of two options from below
});
```

However, when I insert the following at the bottom, it does not work:

```
field = screen.getByLabelText("MySelectField");
expect(field).toHaveValue("1");
```

and gives the following error message:

```
Expected the element to have value: 1
Received:
```

But, when I wrap it in a `setTimeout` with just 1ms delay, it does work:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  field = screen.getByLabelText("MySelectField");
  expect(field).toHaveValue("1");
}, 1);
```

It feels like there should be a more elegant way of writing this without `setTimeout`. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

When I am using react-testing-library I tend to use render when I have events to interact with.
For instance:

In my App.js I have this code on the return method

```
  const handleChoice = () => {};

  const attributes = [
    { label: "One", value: "1" },
    { label: "Two", value: "2" },
    { label: "Three", value: "3" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <select onChange={handleChoice} data-testid="MySelectField">
        <option value="0">Zero</option>
        {attributes.map((item) => {
          return (
            <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
              {item.label}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
```

then my test would be something like this:

```
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
    
import App from "./App";
    
it("changes value after selecting another field", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<App />);
  let field = getByTestId("MySelectField");
  expect(field).toHaveValue("0");

  fireEvent.change(field, { target: { value: "1" } });
  expect(field.value).toBe("1");

  fireEvent.change(field, { target: { value: "3" } });
  expect(field.value).toBe("3");
  // Insert one of two options from below
});
```

Take a look in this sandbox to see it working.
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-https-hzi5n?file=/src/App.spec.js

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but your answer is about Input fields, not Select fields. Also, when I use object destructuring for render methods, eslint throws errors at me to avoid doing that.

Comment: You're welcome. I am not sure what are errors you're having. But updated for a select field one. Please check eslint rules for destructing. It's pretty standard on Javascript. Let me know if can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor) instead of `setTimeout`:

```
import {waitFor} from '@testing-library/react'

...

await waitFor(() => screen.getByLabelText("MySelectField").toHaveValue("1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is that it takes a finite amount of time for your app to react (excuse the pun) to the change that has occurred - specifically, it needs to re-render.

And yes, there is a nicer way - [the `waitFor` function](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor) from `testing-library/react`:

```
import { screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

...

  it("changes value after selecting another field", async () => {

    ...

    fireEvent.change(field, { target: { value: "1" } });

    await waitFor(async () => {
      field = screen.getByLabelText("MySelectField");
      expect(field).toHaveValue("1");
    });
  }
```

Note that the entire test body (i.e. after the test's name) has to be declared `async` in order to be able to `await` the new `waitFor` block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that results in the same error :/